# Oracle SQL Create PDF from Data

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am trying to create a **Probability Density Function** from data in an Oracle SQL table through a SQL query. So consider the below table:

```
Name  |  Spend
--------------
Anne  |  110
Phil  |  40
Sue   |  99
Jeff  |  190
Stan  |  80
Joe   |  90
Ben   |  100
Lee   |  85
```

Now if I want to create a PDF from that data I need to count the number of times each customer spends with in a certain quanta (between 0 and 50 or between 50 and 100). An example graph would look something like this (forgive my poor ascii art):

```
5|
4|  *
3|  * 
2|  * *
1|* * * *
 |_ _ _ _ 
  5 1 1 2 
  0 0 5 0 
    0 0 0
```

So the axis are:

- X-Axis: Is the buckets
- Y-Axis: is the number of customers

I am currently using the Oracle SQL **CASE function** to determine whether the spend falls within the bucket and then summing the number of customers that do. However this is taking forever as it there are a couple of **million records**.

Any idea on how to do this effectively?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [WIDTH_BUCKET](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions234.htm#SQLRF06163) function.

```
select bucket , count(name) 
  from (select name, spend,
               WIDTH_BUCKET(spend, 0, 200, 4) bucket
          from mytable
       )
group by bucket
order by bucket;
```

Here I have divided the range 0 to 200 into 4 bucket. And the function assigns a bucket number to each value. You can group by this bucket and count how many reocrds fall in each bucket.

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/15477).

You can even display the actual bucket range.

```
select bucket,
       cast(min_value + ((bucket-1) * (max_value-min_value)/buckets) as varchar2(10))
       ||'-'
       ||cast(min_value + ((bucket) * (max_value-min_value)/buckets) as varchar2(10)),
       count(name) c 
  from (select name,
               spend,
               WIDTH_BUCKET(spend, min_value, max_value, buckets) bucket
          from mytable)
 group by bucket
 order by bucket;
```

Sample [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/15495).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) y_axis,
     X_AXIS
FROM
     (SELECT COUNT(*)y_axis,
          CASE
               WHEN spend <= 50 THEN 50
               WHEN spend < 100 AND spend > 50 THEN 100 
               WHEN spend  < 150 AND spend >= 100 THEN 150
               WHEN spend  < 200 AND spend >= 150 THEN 200
          END x_axis
     FROM your_table
     GROUP BY spend
     )
GROUP BY X_AXIS;

    y_axis x_axis
-----------------
    4   100
    1   50
    1   200
    2   150
```