# How to group 3 days in one group by using dense_rank() sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need sql to make 3 days in a group. Means like

```
4 Aug 2013 - 6 Aug 2013 as first group..
7 Aug 2013 - 9 Aug 2013 as second group..
10 Aug 2013 - 12 Aug 2013 as third group..
```

**Assuming now is 8 august,**

```
5 Aug- 7 Aug group in first group
8 Aug - 10  group as second group
11 Aug - 13 Aug as third group
```

**This is my part of code:**

```
dense_rank() over (partition by **[3 days]**) order by wip.CURRENT_OPER desc)
as date_priority2,
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) *(MySQL, Oracle, ...)* are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [WIDTH_BUCKET](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions234.htm#SQLRF06163) function for this.
This works for [numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098981/oracle-sql-create-pdf-from-data/18099618#18099618) and datetime values.

Demo at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9a509/1)

**Query**:

```
select date_column,
       width_bucket(date_column,date'2013-08-05',date'2013-08-14',3) grp
from mytable
order by date_column
```

Here the dates between 5th August 00:00:00 to 14th August 00:00:00 are divided into 3 groups.

- First group is from 5th August 00:00:00 to 7th August 23:59:59.
- Second from 8th August 00:00:00 to 10th August 23:59:59.
- Third from 11th August 00:00:00 to 13th August 23:59:59.
- Anything from 14th August 00:00:00 will have group no 4.
- Anything below 5th August 00:00:00 will have group no 0.

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9a509/1/0)**:

```
|                   DATE_COLUMN | GRP |
---------------------------------------
| August, 04 2013 23:59:59+0000 |   0 |
| August, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000 |   1 |
| August, 06 2013 00:00:00+0000 |   1 |
| August, 07 2013 00:00:00+0000 |   1 |
| August, 07 2013 23:59:59+0000 |   1 |
| August, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000 |   2 |
| August, 09 2013 00:00:00+0000 |   2 |
| August, 10 2013 00:00:00+0000 |   2 |
| August, 11 2013 00:00:00+0000 |   3 |
| August, 12 2013 00:00:00+0000 |   3 |
| August, 13 2013 00:00:00+0000 |   3 |
| August, 13 2013 23:59:59+0000 |   3 |
| August, 14 2013 00:00:00+0000 |   4 |
```

You can use this group no in your partition by clause.

**EDIT**
It is not possible to extend the max limit without changing the number of partitions. Better to use something like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/61495/3).

```
select date_column, ceil((trunc(date_column) - date'2013-08-04')/3) grp
from mytable
where date_column >= date'2013-08-05'
order by date_column;
```

Comment: hi.. thanks it works! but i still want to group the date_column into 3 days after 14 August... example: 14 Aug-16 Aug As group 4, 17 Aug-19 Aug As Group 5, 20 Aug- 22 Aug As Group 6...

Comment: oops. That may not be possible. You'll have to do something like Kaf's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this as well (no ranking functions):

```
declare @firstday int = datediff(day,0,'20130804'), 
        @days_per_group int = 3

select mydate,
    (datediff(day,0,mydate)-@firstday) /@days_per_group + 1 as date_priority2
from t
```

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f182/2)

```
|     MYDATE | DATE_PRIORITY2 |
-------------------------------
| 2013-08-04 |              1 |
| 2013-08-05 |              1 |
| 2013-08-06 |              1 |
| 2013-08-07 |              2 |
| 2013-08-08 |              2 |
| 2013-08-09 |              2 |
| 2013-08-10 |              3 |
| 2013-08-11 |              3 |
| 2013-08-12 |              3 |
```